# Get line number clicked using jquery - (count of all <br> inside a <div> before a particular element clicked)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the count of all the `<br>` (i.e. the number of lines before the clicked line) inside the `<div id="myTextFile">`.

```
<div id="myTextFile" >
    <br>Hello abc;
    <br> com.demo;
    <br
    br>
    import org.junit.Test;
    <br>
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    <br>
    import com.jkl;
    <br>
</div>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Not much you can do if the "lines" are not elements themselves.

Comment: Excuse my "ignorance" but, can I ask what exactly is a "clicked line"?

Comment: Are you aware that some of your `<br>` tags are not closed (`<br` and `br>`)? And all your `<br>`-tags should be self-closing too, so they should all look like this: `<br/>`.

Comment: @br001 : what do you mean by `before a particular element clicked` or  `the number of lines before the clicked line` ? Can you please explain more about it ?

Comment: @leo: it could be formulated better, but it's not too hard to understand, br elements cause line breaks in HTML, so every text before or after such an element would be a "line". The clicked line is probably the text the user clicks on with their mouse.

Comment: Your HTML structure is wrong and what do you mean with a line, a horizontal rule not provided in code structure?! Please clarify!

Comment: I don't understand why everyone makes it more complicated than it is.

Comment: @FelixKling because the "clicked line" is ambiguous.

Comment: @FelixKling you probably meant..."not hard to assume", it's not entirely clear what the question is about, specially when things get lost in translation

Comment: @true: what is ambiguous about it?

Comment: Please people vote to close this inadequate question.

Comment: @leo: yeah, that sounds better.

Comment: "The clicked line" What clicked line? The clicked line with the non existence event listener attached to the Element? Or the non-existent A element?

Comment: What is unclear there? There are several lines, separated by `<br/>`. When you clicked at one of these lines, number of `<br/>` before this line should be alerted.

Comment: @true I will vote to close...but first I'd give this guy a chance to re-phrase the question

Comment: There are several lines there. Which line does he want to stop counting at?

Comment: @true: that's the problem, the OP doesn't know where/how to bind the event listener. Don't know why you are mentioning a elements at all.

Comment: This escalated quickly, haha.. OP please clarify, people (including me) are confused!

Comment: @Felix Kling 'A' was just an example Element, but it can be substituted with anything.

Comment: @true: the user may click any line and the OP wants to count all br elements before that.

Comment: @true the line that you are clicked on. Yes, it will be very hard to count anything, because click handler can be only on `<div id="myTextFile" >`

Comment: There we go! @FelixKling Now It makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, that **every line ends up with** `<br/>`:

```
<div id="myTextFile" >
    <br/>
    Hello abc;<br/>
    com.demo;<br/>
    <br/>
    import org.junit.Test;<br/>
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;<br/>
    import com.jkl;<br/>
</div>
```

We can use something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#myTextFile", function(event)
{
    var thisEl = $(this);
    var clickOffset = event.pageY - thisEl.offset().top;
    var lineHeight = thisEl.height() / thisEl.find('br').length;
    var lineNumber = Math.floor(clickOffset / lineHeight);
    alert(lineNumber);
});
```

And [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/2kckt8L7/) with this.